# DropDownList index issue

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I am trying to bind a DropDownList from a stored procedure database connection. I am able to populate the dropDownList with the table's unique identity field and "Unit_ID" field. The info populated correctly on the DropDownList. However when selecting a selected item from the list and storing the value into the stored procedure insert I received an index out of range error. Here is my code:

```cs
private void DisplayUnitType()
{

  SqlConnection Db_Connection = new SqlConnection(Utilities.PageUtils.ConStr);
  SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("SM_GET_UNITS", Db_Connection);
  DA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  DataSet DS = new DataSet();
  DA.Fill(DS, "Units");
  this.DropDownList_Unit_Type.DataSource = DS.Tables["Units"].DefaultView;
  this.DropDownList_Unit_Type.DataTextField = "Unit_Name";
  this.DropDownList_Unit_Type.DataValueField = "Unit_ID";
  this.DropDownList_Unit_Type.DataBind();
  //
}

protected void Button_Submit_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  RegisterUser();
}
private void RegisterUser()
{
  string UnitAdministratorInfo = string.Empty;
  try
    {

      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Utilities.PageUtils.ConStr);
      // format Validation code
      string code = Utilities.PageUtils.MD5encrypt(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + Session["User_Id"].ToString());
      // define data reader7
      SqlCommand cmdInsertUser = new SqlCommand("RG_INSERT_NEW_USER2",conn);
      cmdInsertUser.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit_Id", this.DropDownList_Unit_Type.SelectedItem.Value); //Trying to insert unique item value from dropdown to here
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Validation_Code",code);
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Id",Session["User_Id"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name",Session["First_Name"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name",Session["Last_Name"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",Utilities.PageUtils.MD5encrypt(Session["Password"].ToString()));
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middle_Name",Session["Middle_Name"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_Address",Session["Email_Address"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color_Id",1);
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DSN",Session["DSN"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone",Session["Phone"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip_Code",Session["Zip_Code"].ToString());
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Organization",Session["Organization"].ToString());
      conn.Open();
      cmdInsertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmdInsertUser.Parameters.Clear();
      conn.Close();
    }
  catch(SqlException ex)
    {
      ErrorHandler.Catcher.CatchToDb(ex, "Register2.aspx", Request, Utilities.PageUtils.ConStr);
      Response.Write(Session["User_Id"].ToString() + "<br>" + "</ br>");
      Response.Write(ex.ToString());
      if(ex.ToString().IndexOf("duplicate") != -1 || ex.InnerException.ToString().IndexOf("duplicate") != -1)
        {
          if(Session["User_Id"] == null || Session["User_Id"].ToString() == "") Response.Redirect(Utilities.PageUtils.ErrorPage+"?Error_Message=An error occurred while processing your registration.  Please try again.  If the problem persists, please notify a system administrator.", false);
          else
            {
              Session["User_Id"] = Session["User_Id"].ToString() + "1";
              RegisterUser();
              return;
            }
        }
    }
  try
    {
```

Here is my error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Source Error: 


Line 126:           catch(SqlException ex)
Line 127:           {
Line 128:               ErrorHandler.Catcher.CatchToDb(ex, "Register2.aspx", Request, Utilities.PageUtils.ConStr);
Line 129:               Response.Write(Session["User_Id"].ToString() + "<br>" + "</ br>");
Line 130:               Response.Write(ex.ToString());


Source File: g:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\myWebSite\Register2.aspx.cs    Line: 128 

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +7493656
   System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseGetKey(Int32 index) +13
   System.Collections.Specialized.KeysCollection.Get(Int32 index) +11
   System.Collections.Specialized.KeysCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +7
   ErrorHandler.Catcher.CatchToDb(Exception ex, String User_Id, HttpRequest Req, String ConStr) +1670
   Register2.RegisterUser() in g:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\NacWebSite\Register2.aspx.cs:128
   Register2.Button_Submit_Click1(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in g:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\myWebSite\Register2.aspx.cs:93
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3649; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3648
```

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, the error seems to be coming from the `ErrorHandler.Catcher.CatchToDb` call. You probably have an SqlException too if that code gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't a value for Session["User_ID"], and in the catch block you are trying to reference it with

`Response.Write(Session["User_Id"].ToString()....`

You could try something like:

`string user_ID = Session["User_Id"] != null? Session["User_Id"].ToString(): "No value for Session[User_Id]"`

`Response.Write(user_ID + "...")`